# In dilithium (post quantum signature algorithm), how have the authors precomputed the table of zetas for NTT?

Tags: signature, post-quantum-cryptography, dilithium

I am trying to understand the design rationale of in place NTT in Dilithium. I know that how the splitting of polynomials is done but I cant seem to map this approach to the precomputed table of zetas that is present in the authors code. I have attached the array of values as well. Specifically speaking, is there a way to calculated these values by ourselves? If yes, then how can this be done? Any help regarding this would be very very helpful.[image]

Comment: please give a link to a definition of zeta or explain it. same for NTT. it is a good idea to make your questions detailed and complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not try to implement the algorithm myself but those values are powers of $\zeta = 1753 \in \mathbb{Z}_q$ (as hinted by the name) in the Montgomery form where $q = 8380417$ and the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_q$ are represented not as $\{0,\dots, 8380416\}$ but as $\{-\frac{8380416}{2},\dots,0,\dots, \frac{8380416}{2}\}$. Montgomery form is calculated by multiplying by $2^{32}$ and reducing $\mod q$.

Source: https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.204.ipd.pdf (Section 8.5 mainly)

In more detail, each value is $\zeta_k = \zeta^{\text{brv}(k)}\mod q$. Where $\text{brv}()$ is the bit reversal operation (see the specification for definition), e.g., $\text{brv}(1)=128,\text{brv}(2)=64$. This corresponds with the values listed.

$\zeta_1 = \zeta^{\text{brv}(1)}=\zeta^{128} \mod q = 4808194$

Now we convert to Montgomery representation and the $\mathbb{Z}_q$ representation.

$4808194\cdot 2^{32} \mod q = 25847$. We get the second value. Similarly,

$\zeta_2 = \zeta^{\text{brv}(2)}=\zeta^{64} \mod q = 3765607$

$3765607\cdot 2^{32} \mod q = 5771523$. This is bigger than $\frac{8380416}{2}$ so we need to reduce.

We need to find a number $\alpha$ in $\{-\frac{8380416}{2},\dots,0,\dots, \frac{8380416}{2}\}$ s.t. $\alpha = 5771523 \mod q$ which is $5771523-q=-2608894$ which is the third value in the array.

The first value in the array ($0$) seems to be just a placeholder to properly index the array (since you want to access elements at indices $1-255$ and not $0-254$. Since in the code they do pre-increment https://github.com/pq-crystals/dilithium/blob/master/ref/ntt.c#L56.

Comment: Thank you Sir. This is the exact solution that I was looking for.